# How can I dismiss Android Settings menu programmatically?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I've extended Deitel's "Flag Quiz" (Android for Programmers...App Driven...) to (among other things) allow user to display a small flag for comparison with the given flag. The user taps `SHOW FLAG` and then gets a list of countries, taps one, and it's returned and shown (as ... shown below).

[image]

The only problem I'm having is that after tapping the desired country, the `Settings` preferences screen shows (see below). I guess this is because `SHOW FLAG` is part of it, but I want the next thing the user sees after selecting country from list is to be the screen above. There is **no need to see the screen below**, so there's definitely **no reason to have to press the back button**--**how to avoid?**

[image]

---

FYI, here is a trace and relevant code snippets (I can think of no reason to show any `xml`):

`MainActivity.java`:

```
07-06 17:25:48.305  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/opOptionsItemSelected? item is <Show flag> -----------------------
07-06 17:25:48.350  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/Here's where? to get flag
07-06 17:25:48.688  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/onOptionsItemSelected? Show flag showFlag is true
`FlagActivity.java`:
07-06 17:25:48.768  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/FlagAct? onCreate
07-06 17:25:51.707  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/returnToA from FlagAct? Anguilla!!!
`SettingsActivity`:
07-06 17:25:51.751  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/onCreate? SettingsActivity
(not me)
07-06 17:25:51.783  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/Resources? Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x3 a=-1}
07-06 17:25:51.786  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/Resources? Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x7d0 a=-1}
`MainActivity.java`:
07-06 17:25:55.554  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/entering? onActivityResult in MainActivity
07-06 17:25:55.569  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/onActResult? in Main Act show one flag Anguilla
`QuizFragment.java`:
07-06 17:25:55.591  32269-32269/com.dslomer64.flagquiz W/in showAFlag? country: Anguilla
```

`MainActivity.java`, which is where `Preferences` are kept and options are selected 
and result of calling `FlagActivity` (`onActivityResult`) is processed:

```
   @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
      Log.w("opOptionsItemSelected", "item is <" + item.getTitle() + "> -----------------------");
      Intent preferencesIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
      startActivity(preferencesIntent);
      Button getData =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
      Intent intent = new Intent(
                                  MainActivity.this,
                                  FlagActivity.class
                                 );
      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

      Log.w("onOptionsItemSelected", "" + item.toString() + " showFlag is " + showFlag);
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); // to SettingsActivity.onCreate
   }

     @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
        Log.w("entering","onActivityResult in MainActivity");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String enteredData = data.getStringExtra("Data");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Returned " + enteredData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
            country = enteredData;
            Log.w("onActResult "," in Main Act show one flag " + country);
            quizFragment.showAFlag(country); 
        // ABOVE IS WHERE FLAG IS SHOWN ^^^
        }
    }
```

`FlagActivity.java`, which is where the listview is processed:

```
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flag);
    Log.w("FlagAct", " onCreate");
    flagAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, flagArray);
    setListAdapter(flagAdapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
}

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        String country = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra("Data", country);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), country + "!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("returnToA from FlagAct", country + "!!!");
        finish();
    }
}; // end itemClickListener
```

.
    `SettingsActivity.java`:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity // hosts SettingsFragment in portrait mode
{
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.w("onCreate", "SettingsActivity");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` using the `setOnPreferenceChangeListener()` method.

Then, when the country is changed, call the `finish()` method to exit your activity

Comment: I didn't try this, but as my own Answer shows... problem solved. The reason your good idea might not have any effect is that I don't think that I change any preferences in the process. However, you may have answered the Question. I did NOT. I fixed what was making me ask the Question. I just accepted your answer. If I DO put back in the two offending lines and try your idea and it works, I'll post.

Comment: I haven't used those methods before, so I may not be on the right track. Here's what I tried but it didn't remove the `Settings` screen:     `private Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    };`

Comment: I'm short-sighted. My "fix" (that I have requested to delete) DID fix the problem I had BUT it made it impossible to use ANY `Settings`. So I'll have to take back the Answer I checked for you, unless I can use your Answer to fix my problem.

Comment: You are calling the finish() method from an anonymous class and not from the Activity itself, so it might be the reason it doesn't work. But, I don't exactly understand what you said in your answer for the fix, so maybe this method isn't what you want.

Comment: Heh...  read my comment of 78 seconds ago ... still have problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by modifying `onOptionsItemSelected`, but I did not do so in terms of how I asked the Question.

```
  showFlag = (item.toString().equals("Show flag"));

  if(showFlag)                     // If the Settings buttonpress requested a flag,
  {                                // start the activity for it
      Intent intent = new Intent(  
              MainActivity.this,
              FlagActivity.class
              );
      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
   }                               // but don't start a preferences activity.

   else                            // But if the Settings buttonpress was NOT 'Show flag',
   {                               // start a preferences activity.

      Intent preferencesIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
      startActivity(preferencesIntent);
   };
```

I still don't know (and don't need to) how to "dismiss" a `Settings` screen.

But it would be good to know how to do so, if it's possible.

Comment: There may be a moral here: if you think you need to "dismiss the Settings screen", maybe you shouldn't have opened one in the first place. (I.e., what `if` statement might provide relief?)